# jQuery Take class name, and append its name to specific css rule?

Tags: jquery, css, append, classname

For example, if I have my HTML code like this:

```
<div class="color-ff0000"></div>
```

Is it posible for jQuery to take anything after `"color-"` and append it to class like this

```
color:ff0000
```

Basically to create dynamic classes?

**I found what I need and here is the answer:**

```js
$("[class*='color'], [class*='bgcolor']").each(function() {
    var elClasses = $(this).attr('class').split ( ' ' );
    var elCur = $(this);
    for (var index in elClasses) {
        if (/^color-\w+$/.test(elClasses[index])) {
            var classColor = elClasses[index].split ( '-' )[1];
            elCur.css('color', '#' + classColor);
        }
        if (/^bgcolor-\w+$/.test(elClasses[index])) {
          var classBgColor = elClasses[index].split ( '-' )[1];
            elCur.css('background-color', '#' + classBgColor);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.height{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-673AB7 height dfg  sefg bgcolor-ff0000 "><h1>Banana Developer</h1></div>

<div class="color-eeeeee height dfg  sefg bgcolor-212121 "><h1>Banana Developer</h1></div>
```

Also don't know why this question is marked as duplicate, the question is completely different from the one linked above. Also couldn't find this anywhere else on stackoverflow.

Comment: you may use substring(start,end) method of JavaScript.

Comment: Get the class, split it on the dash, and take the last part.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the class name by the dash, pop off the last part and append:

```js
var _theDiv = $('div');
var className = _theDiv.attr('class');
console.log(className);
var color = className.split('-').pop();
console.log(color);
_theDiv.addClass(color);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-ff0000">Hi</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I get the part of class I need with this, it's showing up in console log... How can I add *#* to it and append it to css "color= # _(var color)_ "

Thanks for your answer

Comment: I don't think you can add to your css file like that with js.  If you don't want to have a class for every color, you can just add the style directly with an inline style if you want like: _theDiv.css('color', color);

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot, just to point to others if they need it sometime, it is actually `_theDiv.css('color', '#' + color);` instead of `_theDiv.css('color', color);` ... But you could also add hashtag to color variable...

Comment: Np and good point sorry you are using the hex value, not color name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    (function($){
     var class_id = 1;
    $("body div").each(function(){
        var className = $(this).attr('class'); 
        var color_split = className.split('-'); 
        var new_class = "class_" + class_id;
        $("#style_block").append("." + new_class + "{" + color_split[0] + ":" + color_split[1] + ";" + "}");
        $(this).addClass(new_class );

        class_id++;
     }); 
 })(jQuery);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<style type="text/css" id="style_block"></style>
<div class="color-#ff0000">test1</div>
<div class="background-#ff0000">test2</div>
<div class="color-blue">test3</div>
```